# update parent table column value by child table's maximum value

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

This is my tables .

Table1

```
    Id     Name    DateTime   Flag
    ==========================
    1      Name1      -        0
    2      Name2      -        1
    3      Name3      -        1
```

Table2

```
    Id     Tb1Id   DateTime
    =======================
    1       1      20-09-2017
    2       1      01-09-2018
    3       2      01-09-2016
    4       2      02-09-2015 
    5       3      06-09-2016 
    6       3      10-09-2019
```

I want to join those two tables by where Table1.Id = Table2.Tb1Id and get the maximum datetime value from Table2, **update** this value to table1's DateTime column where Table1's Flag is equal to 1.

```
    Id     Name     DateTime
    ========================
    2      Name2    01-09-2016
    3      Name3    10-09-2019
```

This is how I tried so far.

```
UPDATE Table1
SET DateTime = 
(
SELECT MAX(T2.UpdatedAt) as UpdatedAt FROM Table1 AS T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS T2
ON T1.Id = T2.Tb1Id
WHERE T1.Flag = 1
GROUP BY T2.UpdatedAt
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an update join here:

```
UPDATE t1
SET DateTime = t2.MaxDateTime
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Tb1Id, MAX(DateTime) AS MaxDateTime
    FROM Table2
    GROUP BY Tb1Id
) t2
    ON t1.Id = t2.Tb1Id
WHERE
    t1.Flag = 1;
```

The problem with your current query is that it never correlated the records in the outer update on `Table1` with anything happening inside the `SET` clause.  But, I would use an update join here, because it is easier to read.

Note that if you think you would have to run this update frequently, you might want to consider just using a query/view which reports the max dates from the second table along with the data from the first table.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple JOIN as

```
CREATE TABLE T1(
  ID INT,
  Name VARCHAR(45),
  Date_Time DATETIME,
  Flag INT
);

INSERT INTO T1 (ID, Name, Flag) VALUES
(1, 'Name1', 0),
(2, 'Name2', 1),
(3, 'Name3', 1);

CREATE TABLE T2(
  ID INT,
  Tb1Id INT,
  Date_Time DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO T2 VALUES
(1, 1, '2017-09-20'),
(2, 1, '2018-01-09'),
(3, 2, '2016-09-01'),
(4, 2, '2015-09-02'), 
(5, 3, '2016-09-06'), 
(6, 3, '2019-09-10');

;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT T1.ID,
         T1.Name, --You can remove this cause I thought you want a SELECT
         MAX( T2.Date_Time ) Date_Time
  FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2
  ON T1.Id = T2.Tb1Id
  WHERE T1.Flag = 1
  GROUP BY T1.ID,
           T1.Name --And this one too
)
UPDATE T1
SET Date_Time = CTE.Date_Time
FROM T1 INNER JOIN CTE
ON T1.Id = CTE.Id;

SELECT *
FROM T1;
```

**Returns:**

```
+----+-------+---------------------+------+
| ID | Name  |      Date_Time      | Flag |
+----+-------+---------------------+------+
|  1 | Name1 |                     |    0 |
|  2 | Name2 | 01/09/2016 00:00:00 |    1 |
|  3 | Name3 | 10/09/2019 00:00:00 |    1 |
+----+-------+---------------------+------+
```

**[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=99dd40f01016afc6643287fbc49e7278)**